# Which XML format for images

Tags: android, xml, view

I want to create a custom  view which is supposed to look like this :

IMAGE-TEXT-BUTTON

To do this I want to define my view like this

```
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="chat_Bubble">
        <attr name="text" format="string" />
        <attr name="image" format="??"></attr>
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

Sadly I do not know which format to use for an image

Answer (score 0):

> Sadly I do not know which format to use for an image

it depends. If the image is defined in the drawable you can use `integer`. Retrieving it is easy. If you want to support both, resources and bitmap on the sdcard, you will probably need to use a `string`. In this case you will check if you have a Bitmap with that name on your disk cache or a drawable resource that matches the string you provided

Answer (score 0):

If the image references another resource id (e.g, `"@drawable/myimage"`) you need to use `reference`.

```
format="reference"
```

Other common formats include:

- string
- float
- integer
- color
- boolean
- dimension
- enum
- flag
- fraction

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml is a good guide.